# Alternative to template variables?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I'm building a binary search tree. As the generic person I am, I want to allow all types to be able to act as keys to nodes in the tree.

So I came up with the following:

```
class foo
{
private:
    template<class T>
    struct node
    {
        T key;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node<>* _root;  //point of interest
public:
    //.....
    template<class T>
    void insert(const T& key);
};
```

As I insert the nodes into the tree, I can create node objects according to the type of the `key`, but I don't know how to declare the `_root` in such a way (when using `insert` on an empty tree, I can easily pick the type for `_root`).

I believe C++14's template variables can help me here, but unfortunately MSVC's compiler hasn't implemented that feature yet.

**Question:** How do I declate `_root` in the most generic way? How did people do it in the past?

Comment: You are overgeneralizing. Make <T> a template argument to foo, as your node can only be of a certain type anyway.

Comment: To clarify: You want a *single tree* to be able to have multiple different types of keys in it?

Comment: Have you thought ahead about how this would be implemented? How should keys be compared, etc, if you don't know their types? Remember that types need to be known at compile time.

Comment: I don't believe that template variables would be of any help here. Maybe what you want is `boost::any`.

Comment: Really? you are "building a binary search tree" and you are calling it `foo`?

Comment: So as I take it from your answers, it's impossible to have one node hold a long value and the other double for example?

Comment: @MikeNakis foo is the name of life.

Comment: @DeiDei, but that would mean you effectively need two roots, right? Since your node will only point to the node of the same type.

Comment: templates implement compiles time polymorphism; What you describe is run time polymorphism. For that you will need class inheritance. (Maybe)

Comment: Microsoft's C++ comipiler is what my friend matt calls “its C++ Jim but not as we know it” (I don't know why he calls me Jim). Just change your compiler `g++` is an excellent compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just storing nodes is not a problem:

```
class foo
{
    struct node
    {
        virtual ~node() {}
        node * left;
        node * right;
    }

    template<typename T>
    struct key_node: node
    {
        T key;
        ~value_node() {}
    }

    node *root;
};
```

The problem will come when you want to access the key value within a node (because you will need to store the type information somehow).

Alternately, you can use boost::any instead of a T template:

```
class foo
{
    struct node
    {
        boost::any key;
        node * left;
        node * right;
    }

    node *root;
};
```

... and use the interface of boost::any to get the value of they key (but even here you will probably need information on the type stored in any before you can access it in a generic way).

Comment: Actually the problem comes before trying to access the key from a node. The first problem comes when you need to compare keys to insert them in the correct order.

Comment: That could be solved with something like [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)